# How to apply d-flex on certain screen sizes only in Vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox, media-queries, vuetify.js

I've got a vue.js application using Vuetify. I've got a table that looks like this:

[image]

Here's the code for it:

```
<v-card class="mb-3 px-3">
  <v-card-title class="px-0">
      <div class="headline">Items</div> 
  </v-card-title>
  <v-container fluid pa-0>
  <v-layout row wrap py-3>
      <v-flex xs9 sm6 md9>
          <v-label>Item</v-label>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex sm2 md1 class="text-xs-center hidden-xs-only"><v-label>Col 1</v-label></v-flex>
      <v-flex sm2 md1 class="text-xs-center hidden-xs-only"><v-label>Col 2</v-label></v-flex>
      <v-flex sm2 md1 class="text-xs-center hidden-xs-only"><v-label>Col 3</v-label></v-flex>
  </v-layout>
  <v-divider></v-divider>
  </v-container>
  <v-form>
    <v-card v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" :id="'index-' + index" flat>
            <v-container fluid pa-0>
                <v-layout row wrap align-center style="min-height: 80px;">
                    <v-flex xs12 sm9><p class="pt-3 pb-3 font-weight-medium">row {{index+1}}</p></v-flex>
                    <v-flex xs4 sm2 md1 class="checkbox-order"><label class="hidden-sm-and-up" style="width: 0;">Col 1:</label><v-checkbox v-model="item.col1" class="checkbox"></v-checkbox></v-flex>
                    <v-flex xs4 sm2 md1 class="checkbox-order"><label class="hidden-sm-and-up" style="width: 0;">Col 2:</label><v-checkbox v-model="item.col2" class="checkbox"></v-checkbox></v-flex>
                    <v-flex xs4 sm2 md1 class="checkbox-order"><label class="hidden-sm-and-up" style="width: 0;">Col 3:</label><v-checkbox v-model="item.col3" class="checkbox"></v-checkbox></v-flex>
                </v-layout>
            </v-container>
        <v-divider v-if="index < items.length - 1"></v-divider>
    </v-card>
  </v-form>
</v-card>
```

When I shrink the page down to less than 600px, it looks like this:

[image]

What we're trying to do here is take the column headers and convert them to labels to the left of each checkbox. That's where the

```
<label class="hidden-sm-and-up">
```

comes into play.

I didn't like how the label and the checkbox are not aligned. Investigating this, I found out that it's because the label and checkbox are being align as columns with the label on top (and aligned left) and the checkbox on the bottom (aligned center). To fix this, I added d-flex to the v-flex of each column:

```
<v-flex xs4 sm2 md1 d-flex class="checkbox-order"><label class="hidden-sm-and-up" style="width: 0;">Col 1:</label><v-checkbox v-model="item.col1" class="checkbox"></v-checkbox></v-flex>
<v-flex xs4 sm2 md1 d-flex class="checkbox-order"><label class="hidden-sm-and-up" style="width: 0;">Col 2:</label><v-checkbox v-model="item.col2" class="checkbox"></v-checkbox></v-flex>
<v-flex xs4 sm2 md1 d-flex class="checkbox-order"><label class="hidden-sm-and-up" style="width: 0;">Col 3:</label><v-checkbox v-model="item.col3" class="checkbox"></v-checkbox></v-flex>
```

That solved the problem for media less than 600px:

[image]

However, when I bring the screen back above 600px, it now looks like this:

[image]

The checkboxes are no longer centered under the column headers. I don't know how to get them centered again.

I'm wondering if there's a way to tell it to apply the d-flex class only when the screen is less than 600px. I know how to apply different classes with v-if but I don't know a way to check for screen size with v-if. I also know how to apply different styles with media queries, but that only works for styles on the same class, not for applying whole different classes.

Does anyone know how to apply the d-flex class only when the screen size is less than 600px?

Comment: Can you please provide a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) example please ?

Comment: In vuetify 2.0.8 + you can use `breakpoints` on `d-flex`, so: `d-md-flex`, or `d-lg-flex`, etc.

Comment: I would like to try that, Ohgodwhy, but there appear to be too many changes from vuetify 1.5.2 to 2.0.8. For example, it chokes on $vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp. I can't find any documentation specifying if this has changed to something else. Do you know of any such documentation?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <v-container class="d-sm-flex d-lg-block"></v-container>
```

The container above has a `display: flex` for **sm** (small screens 600px - 960px) and `display: block` for **lg** (large screens 1264px - 1904px).

You can read more about V[uetify display helpers](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/display/)